# Authorization and Authentication using react - router - dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Hello its my first time here.

I've been trying to solve this issue for the past couple of hours and I cant understand the problem (I'm new to react).

In `PrivateRoute` I am trying to render an Authentication Component based on a session.

- session EXISTS => Authentication Component should render
- NOT EXISTS => a received Component should render

The error I'm getting is:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). 
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

help will be appreciated!

This is what I have done so far:

```js
import Login from './Login'
import Register from './Register'
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Authentication from './Authentication'
import { BrowserRouter , Redirect,  Route, Switch,} from 'react-router-dom'



const  Authorization= ()=>{
  return new Promise ((resolve,reject)=>{
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/content',{credentials:'include'}) //includes cookie from different port
    .then((res)=>res.json())
    .then((data)=>{
      if (data.user=="notLogged"){
        reject(false)
      }else    
        resolve(true)
    })
  })
}

const  PrivateRoute= async ({ component: Component})=> {
  var auth= await Authorization()
  console.log(auth);
  if (auth){
    return <Authentication/> 
  }else{
    return  <Component/>  
  }
}

class Index extends Component{
 
  render(){
    return(
      <BrowserRouter>
      {/* router may have only one child element- switch is the more common */}
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Login}/>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

export default Index
```

Comment: Does this error happen regardless of the answer for `var auth= await Authorization()`?

Comment: No it generates in this line, I had some difficulties returning a result from Authorization, so I tried this using Promises. 
and the error accord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer to my post.

I've been doing this wrong.

This is what I came up with so far

```js
import Login from './Login'
import Register from './Register'
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Authentication from './Authentication'
import { BrowserRouter , Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'


 const PrivvatRoute=({ component: Component, user})=>(
  <Route  render={(props) =>  user==="notLogged" ?  <Component/> : <Authentication user={user} /> } />
)

class Index extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={user:""}
}
 
render(){
 return(
 <BrowserRouter>
 {/* router may have only one child element- switch is the more common */}
    <Switch>
       <PrivvatRoute exact path="/"   component={Login} user={this.state.user}   />
       <PrivvatRoute exact path="/login"   component={Login} user={this.state.user} />
       <PrivvatRoute exact path="/register"  component={Register} user={this.state.user}  />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
)
}


componentWillMount(){
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/content',{credentials:"include"})
  .then((data)=>data.json())
  .then((data)=>{this.setState(data);  console.log(data)
 
 })
 }
}

export default Index
```

and works fine!

Comment: I love seeing people answer their own questions. well done.